# `make` returns error: recipe for target 'libast.la' failed

Tags: software-installation, compiling, make, configure

I am trying to install the [HEASOFT package](http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/lheasoft/ubuntu.html) from source code on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine.
Following the instructions at the link, I first run `./configure` [(see the output here)](http://pastebin.com/SuPvPLrf), but after that, the command `make` returns some errors [(see here)](http://pastebin.com/ucg8tEv1). Unfortunately, I did not realize it immediately, so I have also run `make install`, which might have made the problem worse .

Should I / How can I uninstall the (part of the) software that has been "configurated" by those commands, and how can I reinstall it in a proper way?

Comment: Most often, `make install` just copies the compiled objects from the build directory to the target install directory. I doubt it did any harm. **If** the `Makefile` provides an `uninstall` target (some do, some don't), you could run that (`sudo make uninstall`) to try to clean up the target dir. As an aside, you might want to look at [checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall)

Comment: @steeldriver, unfortunately there is no `uninstall` target for this operation. Do you think that, at this point, `checkinstall` can really help for a clean uninstall thus to start from scratch?

Comment: No, and I don't think you really need to - after you fix the errors and `make` successfully, `make install` should overwrite everything in the target install directory with new stuff anyway.

Comment: @steeldriver, ok. Do you have any other suggestions on how to make the installation successful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem updating some packages with:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Which upgraded the following:

```
Upgrade: python2.7-dev:amd64 (2.7.12-1~16.04, 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1), gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1, 1.8.2-1ubuntu0.2), xserver-common:amd64 (2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.1, 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.2), gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1, 1.8.2-1ubuntu0.2), xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.1, 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.2), imagemagick:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.1, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2), libpulsedsp:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1), pulseaudio:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1), gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1, 1.8.2-1ubuntu0.2), python2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.12-1~16.04, 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1), libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.1, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2), libpython2.7:amd64 (2.7.12-1~16.04, 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1), python2.7:amd64 (2.7.12-1~16.04, 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1), libpython3.5:amd64 (3.5.2-2~16.04, 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1), python3.5:amd64 (3.5.2-2~16.04, 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1), python3.5-minimal:amd64 (3.5.2-2~16.04, 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1), libpython2.7-dev:amd64 (2.7.12-1~16.04, 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1), gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1, 1.8.2-1ubuntu0.2), procps:amd64 (2:3.3.10-4ubuntu2, 2:3.3.10-4ubuntu2.2), libprocps4:amd64 (2:3.3.10-4ubuntu2, 2:3.3.10-4ubuntu2.2), libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1, 1.8.2-1ubuntu0.2), gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1, 1.8.2-1ubuntu0.2), imagemagick-6.q16:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.1, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2), libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.1, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2), python3-distupgrade:amd64 (1:16.04.17, 1:16.04.18), libpulse0:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1), ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:amd64 (1:16.04.17, 1:16.04.18), metacity-common:amd64 (1:3.18.7-0ubuntu0.1, 1:3.18.7-0ubuntu0.2), libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1), tar:amd64 (1.28-2.1, 1.28-2.1ubuntu0.1), libmetacity-private3a:amd64 (1:3.18.7-0ubuntu0.1, 1:3.18.7-0ubuntu0.2), libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1, 1.8.2-1ubuntu0.2), gstreamer1.0-x:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1, 1.8.2-1ubuntu0.2), gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0:amd64 (1.8.2-1ubuntu0.1, 1.8.2-1ubuntu0.2), libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.1, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2), pulseaudio-module-x11:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1), ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:amd64 (1:16.04.17, 1:16.04.18), libpython2.7-minimal:amd64 (2.7.12-1~16.04, 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1), unattended-upgrades:amd64 (0.90ubuntu0.1, 0.90ubuntu0.2), pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1), imagemagick-common:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.1, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.2), libpython3.5-stdlib:amd64 (3.5.2-2~16.04, 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1), libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.12-1~16.04, 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1), libpython3.5-minimal:amd64 (3.5.2-2~16.04, 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1), pulseaudio-utils:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3, 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.1)
```

Afterwards, no errors have been reported by `make` nor `make install`.